# Update Date format in oracle

Tags: database, oracle, oracle-sqldeveloper

I need to convert date format in ORACLE.The current value is **0080-08-24** and i want to convert it into **1980-08-24**
How to update above value?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Try this:

```
update tablename
set datecolumn= add_months(date'0080-08-24',1900*12)
```

Answer (score 1):

Just for completeness, another solution:

```
SELECT TO_DATE('0080-08-24','"00"RR-MM-DD') FROM DUAL;

24-AUG-1980
```

Comment: The output of above query is : 24-AUG-80

Comment: Yep - your NLS date format uses 2-digit years. If you fix your format you will see 1980.